# should I weigh an average net margin calculation of Eurozone banks per number of banks or per asset size to validate parallel trends?

Tags: econometrics, banking, central-banking

I'm trying to perform a DiD regression analysis in order to evaluate whether **bank profitability** has **decreased** with the implementation of a negative interest rate policy (NIRP). The regression is working fine and has reasonable results.

Yet, I have trouble validating the parallel trends assumption graphically. I have two groups (control, treatment) and in that groups there is a great level of heterogeneity depending on the asset size of banks in each country. If I just plot an average, the number of banks in a country has much more influence on the average as compared to the assets of banks in that country. That would imply that for instance Austria has double the influence on average Eurozone margins than France even though France has ten times more assets.

On the other hand if I would weigh the net margins with regards to asset size the research question would heavily depend on the performance of few bulge bracket banks with trillion Euro balance sheet.

I know that this is a very specific question but I could not gather any useful advice on other threads/forums beside the typical DiD parallel trends advices.

[image]